# How to use std::bind inside std::for_each?

Tags: c++

This is a function checking whether or not a given target exists in the container.

```
bool exist(char key, char target,
           std::unordered_map<char, std::unordered_set<char>>& ut_hash_map,
           int recur_depth = 0) {
  auto fn = std::bind(exist, std::placeholders::_1, target, ut_hash_map,
                      recur_depth + 1);
  return (recur_depth <= 1 && (ut_hash_map[key].count(target) == 1 ||
                               std::for_each(ut_hash_map[key].begin(),
                                             ut_hash_map[key].end(), fn)));
}
```

It cannot pass the compilation and the compiler reports:

`error: no match for ‘operator||’ (operand types are ‘bool’ and ‘std::_Bind<bool (*(std::_Placeholder<1>, char, std::unordered_map<char, std::unordered_set<char> >, int))(char, char, std::unordered_map<char, std::unordered_set<char> >&, int)>’)`

How to solve this problem?

Comment: for each returns the functor you pass, I dont know what that is actually good for, but what do you expect by doing `return ... || fn;` ?

Comment: what is the last part of the condition supposed to check?

Comment: Don't use `std::bind`, use lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

`std::for_each` does not return bool, as the error text says. It calls a function on each of the elements in range. Now suppose, some of the calls return true, some - false. What exactly do you expect for_each to return?

I will assume you want all the calls to have returned true. In that case, you need `std::all_of`, instead of `std::for_each`